# OSB 12c rest proxy service security with OWSM

Tags: rest, security, osb

I used OWSM policy Oracle/wss_http_token_service_policy on the  rest based proxy service, it is working fine (authenticating with basic.credentilas) in my local machine weblogic server but not supporting in the dev/test server, so what extra setting is required here? or do we need to use any other policy, I want to use just the basic authentication configured in my realms. Could you please advise.

Comment: Elaborate on "not supporting in the dev/test server". What exactly happens?

Comment: Thanks Trent, Rest proxy is returning the response with out even selecting the basic authorization, or even provided wrong credentilas. So is there any extra settings are needed on the server side for this policy configuration or need to use a different OWSM policy fr this?

Comment: Ok, well first you can test by removing the policy, and enforcing basic auth on the proxy directly. This bypasses OWSM but still hits the default credential store. I expect this to work.

Comment: That probably narrows it down to lack of OWSM integration. You'll need to use the RCU to add OWSM schemas, then extend the OSB domain with OWSM stuff (assuming you have sufficient access to the server). More details are here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/dev.1111/e15866/owsm.htm#OSBDV1712

Comment: Thanks Trent, that option is not availabel to configure, I checked with the suport tam, they are saying all needed configurations are already in place in servers. Could you please elaborate on this:                           Trent - Ok, well first you can test by removing the policy, and enforcing basic auth on the proxy directly. This bypasses OWSM but still hits the default credential store. yu mean to say to use the custom authentication in security settings? but how to pass the basic credentias here?

Comment: How are you deploying your project to test/dev servers? is there a difference in how the services are being deployed to your local machine?